# Can mhddfs mounting options be set via /etc/fstab to respect file permissions?

Tags: mount, permissions, fstab, fuse

I'm currently using `mhddfs` to mount three hard drives into a singluar pool directory. However, due to the `allow_other` option set, all users have full rw permissions in the pool directory (ignoring any set permissions on the files/folders). I know this is expected behaviour as the pool gets mounted as root and any user that changes into the pool's directory gets their permissions elevated to root.

Mount point in `/etc/fstab`:

```
mhddfs#/mnt/disk1,/mnt/disk2,/mnt/disk3 /storage/pool fuse defaults,allow_other,nonempty 0 0
```

It seems that `allow_other` doesn't care which user actually mounted the pool (same thing happens when I manually mount as myself). Naturally, taking that option out correctly limits the pool to my view only (ignoring any groups I'm in) but I want it viewable at the very least to other users in the same group set by the pool's permissions:

```
$ cd /storage && ls -l
drwxr-x--- 2 josh share 4096 Feb 16 17:57 pool
```

Any users in the `share` group should have read/execute perms. I'm currently exposing this pool via NFS, with `all_squash` set and `anongid=1004` (id of share).

Is there a way to use mhddfs so that each user's permissions are properly respected when looking in the mounted pool, while still visible to all users? Somewhat similar to the way NFS's `all_squash` works. Having scoured manuals and other forums, I've turned up bupkiss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed the same problem a few hours ago.
Found some help in a FUSE manual.

The option "default_permissions" seems to do the trick. I've set it in fstab and after a small test it seems to respect the underlying permissions.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.fuse.8.html

Comment: Seven months I have waited for this answer! Thank you so much! I have just remounted my mhddfs entry with this option set and I can confirm it is now adhering to the file permissions set.

Comment: I've been doing some additional testing and it still seems to behave odd. Say i have normal mounts at /mnt/mnt1 and /mnt/mnt2. And a mhddfs mount for both at /mnt/mnt3. I set owner, group and other for mnt1 and mnt2 to have "none" permissions. Then i set /mnt/mnt3 owner, group and other to "read/write". It seems the permissions of mnt1 and mnt2 als get the "read/write" even though it doesn't show in the permissions info. Giving me a headache because i really like mhddfs.